# adding smoothed curves to plot using loess()

Tags: r

I have for example monthly data from this package:

```
install.packages("fma")
library(fma)  
plot(boston)
```

Now I want to try and add to this plot two smoothed curves in different color by using local polynomial regression fitting. I thought I can do that by using the command loess(), I also want to select a small respectively bigger value for the parameter span. However, it's not working really. I can't apply loess(). I don't know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A loess regression requires both x and y variables, but a `ts` object only has a y variable, with the time variable being implicit, so we need to extract the time variable as a numeric variable and regress on it.

You can do this automatically using `geom_smooth` in `ggplot`, with the added benefits of a fully customizable plot and a standard error ribbon.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(fma)  

as.data.frame(boston) %>%
  mutate(date = time(boston)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-date, names_to = "series") %>%
  ggplot(aes(date, value)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_smooth(method = loess, formula = y~x, fill = "lightblue", lty = 2,
              method.args = list(span = 0.5)) +
  facet_grid(series~., scales = "free_y") +
  theme_bw(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: thanks @Allan Cameron. When I try this in RStudio I get the following error message: Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `date = as.Date(boston)`.
Caused by error in `as.Date.default()`:

Comment: @JeffAnderson sorry about that - I have updated with a full reprex that fixes this. If you copy-paste the code into your session this should work for you.

Comment: Thanks @AllanCameron. It works now :). However, I must admit that I am a little bit confused with ggplot. I want the two smoothered curves by using local polynomial regression fitting and I want to select a small respectively bigger value for the parameter span. But I don't see for example the parameter span  when using ggplot. I was using this as a reference in my research/help: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/loess.html

Comment: @JeffAnderson you can pass extra arguments to the `loess` method right inside `geom_smooth`. See my update, where I have changed the `span` parameter.

Comment: I was wondering how is the parameter span affecting the loess estimation internally? and how to interpret the trend estimated by loess in the context of the time series?